# "Hello, WebView" example

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I'm new in android development and I am trying out the WebView example in the official android site.

http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html

But I do everything they say...which is pretty simple: I create the project, edit the layout file, then I add the code, etc. No problems building...but when I launch the app in the simulator I just got a black screen. It is like if the Layout is empty...like if the WebView is not created.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry about that – that link is a bit outdated. The fixed version of this tutorial is available here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

We should remove the old link; I'll file a bug.

And note, the error is that `setContentView` isn't being called.

Comment: Hi Roman,

Thanks for your answer. I've tried the new tutorial and I made it work, although it has a bug too. In the layout, when opening the WebView tag...is hast to be like this:

<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

If not.. it won't build.

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what happened w/ the old example? You mentioned that the error is that setContentView wasn't being called, but I was calling. My onCreate method looked like this:

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);
     webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
     webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
     webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");         
    )

I have the same code in other project and it works, but the layout file is different.

thanks in advance!

Comment: You're right about the new tutorial -- it's missing `xmlns:android`. The old tutorial was missing `setContentView` but I'm not sure what other error you were having besides that. If you post all of your previous code, someone may be able to spot the error.

Answer (score 2):

in oncreate method add `WebView.enablePlatformNotifications();`

in manifest file add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

now it works fine...

Answer (score 0):

```
    webview_id = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview_id);
    webview_id.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript
    WebSettings webSettings = webview_id.getSettings();
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(true);
    webSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview_id.setInitialScale(90);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webview_id.requestFocusFromTouch();
    webview_id.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Snackbar.with(getApplicationContext()).dismiss();
            Snackbar.with(getApplicationContext()) // context
                    .text(description) // text to display
                    .show(MainActivity.this);
        }
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });


    if(isNetworkAvailable()){

        webview_id .loadUrl("http://helloworld.org/");
    }else{
        Snackbar.with(getApplicationContext()).dismiss();
        Snackbar.with(getApplicationContext()) // context
                .text("Please Check your Internet Connection") // text to display
                .show(MainActivity.this);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: you should also write some text to explain what you have done. Source code only answers are not good.